# how to debug request api under cumulocity

Tags: api, cumulocity

how to debug request api under cumulocity

I tried to call api cumulocity with postman but it does not work error 404 moreover seems to me that I have configured the environment correctly under postman
I'm trying to debug I don't know how

Comment: Maybe you can share more details of what you did, share your API call etc.

Comment: I want to access tenant via a rest api to return all roles for example

Comment: I want to access tenant via a rest api to return all roles for example  https://your-tenant-name.cumulocity.eu  error 404